# Overriding the login jsp in Liferay 7

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, liferay, hook, liferay-7

In Liferay 7, I would like to override the login jsp.

As a first test, I've tried successfully to override the bottom-ext.jsp through the following link

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-core-jsps

After that and because the login.jsp is not a core jsp in Liferay 7 but a module jsp, I've tried the following link :

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-jsps

But unfortunately after trying deploying* and starting, nothing has changed in my login view whereas I've added some custom html in the login.jsp file.

Does anyone has followed the previous tutorial successfully ?

For my failed test, I have :

1. First retrieved the example project

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-workspace/modules/blade.hook.jsp

2. Next modified the login.jsp with custom html between lines 18 and 20

```html
<p style="color: red">changed</p>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<c:choose>
```

3. The Liferay Module Project seems not be deployed* because nothing is written in the Eclipse console during deployment. Usually, with my other project modules, I have the following message :

16:31:49,741 INFO  [pool-8-thread-2][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED project.module_name_1.0.0 [864]

But not in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hooks always remain in resolved state in liferay 7,
Also when u deploy that hook, nothing seems to be coming on the log, seems to indicate that your login portlet version is different.

Check your version in gogo shell & Replace it in this line in bnd.bnd

```
Fragment-Host: com.liferay.login.web;bundle-version="1.0.0"
```

When u deploy this, a message should come like  stopped & started login.web,
This is how JSP Fragments hook works.

The latest Liferay IDE 3.1.0 (December Release) provides option to create JSP fragment hook, try that if you are facing issues via BLADE CLI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My com.liferay.login.web is in version 1.0.7, so I've changed the bundle-version but nothing deployed in the console.

Comment: @Vincent still the same behaviour ? no  logs at all ?

Comment: Yes, I've just tried with the blade cli.
Create a project module with fragment as template, I follow this documentation :

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-modules-with-blade-cli
The first time, I try to deploy, I obtain the following error :
invalid operation on a fragment liferay
Now, I don't have anything, neither log messages nor error messages.

Comment: @Vincent : is the jar created, if yes can you manually keep it in the deploy folder.

Comment: I've just tried to drop the jar into the deploy folder, I get the following message :
10:00:38,529 INFO  [com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.auto.AutoDeployScanner][AutoDeployDir:252] Processing com.liferay.login.web.jar
But nothing seems deployed.
Where can I check that the module is deployed or not ?

Comment: I've restarted my server and get the following stack trace :
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: A bundle is already installed with the name "com.liferay.login.web" and version "1.0.7"
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.install(ModuleContainer.java:254)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.Storage.install(Storage.java:517)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.installBundle(BundleContextImpl.java:146)
 at com.liferay.portal.lpkg.deployer.internal.LPKGBundleTrackerCustomizer.addingBundle(LPKGBundleTrackerCustomizer.java:114)

Comment: seems strange, try removing from osgi/modules, & Keeping your fragment jar again .

Comment: Ok, It works by dropping the jar directly into the deploy folder. 
However, I don't understand why it doesn't work inside Eclipse although my other example with core jsp works fine in Eclipse.

Comment: There's some issue, that's why they updated IDE and you will  be able to see that feature in latest release .you can accept my answer if it helped.

Comment: Ok maybe when the new Liferay IDE plugin will be available (3.1.0) in Eclipse, the problem could be solved.

Comment: it is available, the december release, it has the option to create fragment hook, & it automatically picks up the version

Comment: i posted the link, you can download it .! it has all the new features such as maven module, fragment and all

Comment: Ok thank you, I was searching in the Latest stable release, not in the Latest milestone release

Comment: Ok indeed, the plugin makes the life easier !

Comment: Warning, after some tests, this plugin is not stable, we might have infinite server starting with it :
https://web.liferay.com/fr/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/81387953

Comment: I didnt got any issue ..in previous version i had same issue but it was due to windows 10, it was trying to ping to ipv6 .. may be that's the issue ..i should answer that too :D